# SDE in 2-dimensional time domain

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-differential-equations

Usually an SDE $dX_t = f(X_t,t) + g(X_t,t)dW_t$ is formulated in 1-dimensional time domain, $t\in \mathbb{R}$. However, in principle, the time could be also a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, $t=(t_1,t_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Does someone know some reference studying such a process?

In particular, let's say the process is an OU in both $t_1$ and $t_2$ directions. Can we say something about the limiting process?

Comment: What would $W_{(t_1,t_2)}$ be?

Comment: Not what the Wiener Process would be. I think this is clear. Rather, can we say something about the limiting process of the "OU" $dX_{(t_1,t_2)}$? Is their a stationary distribution corresponding to the limiting process if both $t_1,t_2$ go to infinity?

Comment: Googling for [Brownian sheet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_sheet) should take you somewhere. There has been done a lot of work on infinite dimensional processes also ([Da Prato, Zabczyk](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/stochastic-equations-in-infinite-dimensions/6218FF6506BE364F82E3CF534FAC2FC5)) of which $t_1\mapsto B_{t_1\,,\,.\,}$ is an example when $B_{t_1,t_2}$ is the Brownian sheeet.

Comment: A good buzzword could also be "two-parameter process."

Comment: These are great hints. I will see where this leads me to. Thank you!